# How can I prevent ffmpeg JPG->MP4 from adding a bogus frame?

Tags: ffmpeg

I run

```
>ffmpeg -r 60 -i videotemp\output.%05d.jpg -crf 17 -y output.mp4
```

on 1000 jpgs and get 1001 frames in the mp4, according to the report:

```
frame= 1001 fps=198 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4641kB time=00:00:16.63 bitrate=2285.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=3.28x
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -v trace   2>&1  | grep "distance 0, keyframe 1"

[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005c3c40] AVIndex stream 0, sample 0, offset 30, dts 0, size 773, distance 0, keyframe 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005c3c40] AVIndex stream 0, sample 250, offset eb7b8, dts 64000, size 51525, distance 0, keyfra
me 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005c3c40] AVIndex stream 0, sample 500, offset 204298, dts 128000, size 49208, distance 0, keyf
rame 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005c3c40] AVIndex stream 0, sample 750, offset 32a3bb, dts 192000, size 39394, distance 0, keyf
rame 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005c3c40] AVIndex stream 0, sample 1000, offset 47d648, dts 256000, size 31644, distance 0, key
frame 1
```

I would really prefer ffmpeg not to add this bogus frame.

Answer (score 1):

Change `-r` to `-framerate` which is the correct input option for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1).